# columns added through JDBC do not appear in DBeaver columns

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, dbeaver

I am new to DBs and I just managed to use JDBC to transform a database on DBeaver.

The DB that I created on DBeaver:

[image]

Code used to add new column:

[image]

after querying the db from DBeaver to check it did everything correctly

[image]

I can see that the column has been added but I do not see it here:

[image]

how can I make it so that I see it under `Columns`

Comment: Did you do a refresh

Comment: fml, I even look for it by right clicking on the DB... I figured it would do it by itself... Anyhow ty

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the columns in DBeaver by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.